# SHIFT command does not work on %*

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, parameters, shift

When using the `SHIFT` command to shift the script parameters one position down, I can see the values shift by echo-ing the `%1` parameter:

```
:: scr1.bat
echo %*
echo %1
shift
echo %1
```

Then:

```
> scr1.bat aa bb cc
aa bb cc
aa
bb
```

However, if I echo the parameters list after the shift, it does not seem to change:

```
:: scr2.bat
echo %*
shift
echo %*
```

Then:

```
> scr2.bat aa bb cc
aa bb cc
aa bb cc
```

Why doesn't `SHIFT` work on the full parameters list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found in the [MS document](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shift.mspx?mfr=true), in the remarks section:

> - Using %* with shift
>
> Shift has no affect on the %* batch parameter.

Now one is just left to wonder why?